# Sort file based on name using perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a source folder where many files are there with different name:

```
20160311_TXT_XPL_SLA_Attribution

20160301_TXT_APL_SLA_Attribution

20160301_TXT_XPL_SLA_Attribution

20160302_TXT_APL_SLA_Attribution
```

I have to sort the files based on letters between TXT_***_SLA.

I wrote the Perl script but this is not properly sorting:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

    $dir = "E://Unix";
    my $file;
    my @files;
    opendir (DIR, "$dir");
    while ($file = readdir(DIR)) 
    {
      push (@files, $file);
    }


    print 
         map  { $_->[1] } 
         sort 
         map  { /TXT(.*)SLA/; [$1, $_] }
         @files;

   foreach $file (@files) 
   {
     print "$file\n";
   }

   closedir(DIR);
```

Even I checked the after removing the underscores but don't see any change in sorting patter. I am really new to Perl & it will be great help if someone can tell me where I am going wrong?

Output is coming:

```
20160301_TXT_APL_SLA_Attribution.txt

20160301_TXT_XPL_SLA_Attribution.txt

20160302_TXT_APL_SLA_Attribution.txt

20160311_TXT_XPL_SLA_Attribution.txt
```

Expected is:

```
20160301_TXT_APL_SLA_Attribution.txt

20160302_TXT_APL_SLA_Attribution.txt

20160301_TXT_XPL_SLA_Attribution.txt

20160311_TXT_XPL_SLA_Attribution.txt
```

Regex used:

```
/(TXT)(.*)(SLA)/
```

Comment: Why using `TCT` and `PLA` when it's `TXT` and `SLA` ?

Comment: Sorry, it should be TXT only typo error while putting it in blog

Comment: @noob I have updated it & shared screenshot as well.

Answer (score 4):

There's two problems, both here:

```
print 
     map  { $_->[1] } 
     sort 
     map  { /TXT(.*)SLA/; [$1, $_] }
     @files;
```

First, your [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) is lacking a sort function.  So it's sorting the string versions of your array references like `ARRAY(0x7ff730805468)`.  You need to add something like `sort { $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] }`.

Second, sort does not happen in place.  The output has to be assigned back to `@files`.

Comment: Yes, but code is giving me same output even after adding this code : map  { $_->[1] }                
sort {$a->[0] cmp $b->[0]}   
map  { /TXT(.*)SLA/; [$1, $_] }

Comment: @Deep "...sort does not happen in place. The output has to be assigned back to `@files.`" In other words, you have to do `@files = map {$_->[1]}  sort {$a->[0] cmp $b->[0]} map {/TXT(.*)SLA/;[$1, $_]} @files;`

Comment: I think I have to check what you have suggested by assigning the value back to @files.

Answer (score 2):

A *Schwartzian Transform* is a useful optimisation only when the data set is huge or the sorting function is complex and slow; otherwise it just makes for unclear code. So it's a shame that it has become the go-to pattern any time someone wants to sort by a *function* of the data instead of the data itself

There are a couple of alternatives, and you may prefer a standard sort function like this. The relevant parts of `$a` and `$b` are extracted into `$aa` and `$bb` respectively, and then they are simply compared

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

chomp( my @data = <DATA> );

say for sort {
    my ($aa, $bb) = map { /TXT_([A-Z]+)_SLA/ } $a, $b;
    $aa cmp $bb;
} @data;

__DATA__
20160311_TXT_XPL_SLA_Attribution
20160301_TXT_APL_SLA_Attribution
20160301_TXT_XPL_SLA_Attribution
20160302_TXT_APL_SLA_Attribution
```

#### output

```
20160301_TXT_APL_SLA_Attribution
20160302_TXT_APL_SLA_Attribution
20160311_TXT_XPL_SLA_Attribution
20160301_TXT_XPL_SLA_Attribution
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html):

> If SUBNAME or BLOCK is omitted, sorts in standard string comparison order.

So the following code

```
 sort 
 map  { /TXT(.*)PLA/; [$1, $_] }
 @files;
```

sorts the arrayref values returned from `map` by their stringified value (something like `ARRAY(0x22bcd48)`). The following should sort the arrayrefs by their first element:

```
 sort { $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] }
 map  { /TXT(.*)PLA/; [$1, $_] }
 @files;
```